# Cassandra replication system - how it works

Tags: installation, replication, cassandra

1. Does Cassandra replicate only on write procedure (with chosen consistency level)? Is there any auto-replicate option for absent nodes, if I want symmetric data in every node?
2. If I plug in a new node to the cluster, there is no auto replication. How can I sync data from other nodes with the new one?
3. If I want replication like multimaster (2 nodes) with slave backup (1 node) known from MySQL, what is the proper way to set up and manage that on Cassandra (3 nodes)? How about two nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cassandra replicates on writes, yes, but it also uses [Hinted Handoff](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HintedHandoff), [Read Repair](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadRepair) and [Anti Entropy](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/AntiEntropy) to to reduce the inconsistency window.

If you plugin a new node with auto_bootstrap set to true that node will get the appropriate data from the other nodes in the cluster.

From cassandra.yaml (storage-conf.xml in 0.6.x) about auto_bootstrap:

```
Set to true to make new [non-seed] nodes automatically migrate the right data to themselves.
```