# How Cassandra handle part of cluster desynchronization?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cluster-computing

What is going one when parts of the cluster don't see each other?
For example: when 3/7 of cluster can't communicate with 4/7 cluster for coupe of hours.

Each part of cluster use "hinted handof" for other one part?
The data is rebalanced and replicated in each part of cluster?
If I balance clients to each part of cluster for writes, after join parts of cluster there will by data lost?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027047/cassandra-replication-system-how-it-works/3028078#3028078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, writes to any replica will be replicated to the others once the partition heals.  http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HintedHandoff, http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadRepair, and http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureAntiEntropy all play a role with this.

you can also specify QUORUM or higher ConsistencyLevel and then only writes (or reads) that can see a majority of the replicas will succeed.

Comment: If I will have 32 nodes quorum write seams useless (high write/read latency)? 
In the other hand if I write to both part of splitted cluster (without quorum) the same value replication goes with the timestamp and overwrite data?

Comment: quorum means majority of the replicationfactor.  if you have replicationfactor=32 you are doing it wrong. :)